# Saber o tamanho total do arquivo para baixar

Tags: java, download

Estou com o seguinte código que baixa arquivo da internet

```
public boolean copiar(){
        boolean teste = false;
        try
        {
            String local = System.getProperty("user.dir") +"\\PDV.jar";;
            String archive = "https://github.com/cbcarlos07/PDV-client/blob/master/PDV.jar";            
            InputStream in  = new URL(archive).openStream();
            OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream( local, false );
            long expectedBytes = in.available(); // This is the number of bytes we expected to copy..
            long totalBytesCopied = 0; // This will track the total number of bytes we've copied
            byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
            int len = 0;
            System.out.println("Total: "+expectedBytes);
            while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
                out.write(buf, 0, len);
                totalBytesCopied += len;
                System.out.println("Len: "+len);
                System.out.println("totalCopiado: "+totalBytesCopied);
                double total = ( totalBytesCopied * 100 ) / expectedBytes;
                double percentual = ( totalBytesCopied / expectedBytes ) * 100;
                System.out.println( total );
                System.out.println(percentual+"%");
            }
            System.out.println("");
            in.close();
            out.close();
            teste = true;

        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return teste;
    }
```

Ele funciona, mas eu gostaria de saber antes, qual o tamanho do arquivo para fazer um indicador de progresso

Saber o total do arquivo, quanto foi baixado e quantos falta para baixar, pra fazer até o tempo de download

Comment: Uma alternativa *seria* ler o header `Content-Length`, mas essa URL retorna o header `Transfer-Encoding: chunked`, e nesses casos o `Content-Length` não é retornado (veja mais sobre isso [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4930152), [aqui](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding#Rationale) e [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49627423)). Então acho que nesse caso não tem jeito mesmo...

Answer (score 2):

O tamanho de um recurso HTTP é informado via um cabeçalho HTTP, o `Content-length`. Em HTTP 1.1, é possível omitir essa informação, desde que seja usada o cabeçalho `Transfer-encoding: chunked`. Para recursos estáticos, como esse daí possivelmente é, é fácil saber o tamanho do recurso *antes* de se começar a transmissão, mas tem casos em que não é possível.

Para saber a partir do Java, você precisa de algum jeito ter acesso à conexão HTTP, para então resgatar os cabeçalhos. Não vi como fazer isso através do [`URL.openStream()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#openStream--), mas é plausível obter essa informação via [`URL.openConnection()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#openConnection--). Dá para obter os cabeçalhos HTTP porque uma das subclasses de `URLConnection` (a saída de `URL.openConnection()`) é [`HttpURLConnection`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html). Além disso, a própria classe `URLConnection` fornece o método [`URLConnection.getContentLength()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#getContentLength--) (ou, segundo a documentação, o [`URLConnection.getContentLengthLong()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#getContentLengthLong--), que é preferível).

> Note que na documentação está explícito que pode retornar -1 se o recurso for de tamanho desconhecido!

Modifiquei o mínimo possível o seu código para obter o tamanho esperado do recurso e de algum jeito informar quando não é possível saber isso:

```java
public boolean copiar(){
        boolean teste = false;
        try
        {
            String local = System.getProperty("user.dir") +"\\PDV.jar";;
            String archive = "https://github.com/cbcarlos07/PDV-client/blob/master/PDV.jar";
            URLConnection conn  = new URL(archive).openConnection();
            InputStream in  = conn.getInputStream();
            OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream( local, false );
            long expectedBytes = conn.getContentLengthLong(); // This is the number of bytes we expected to copy..
            long totalBytesCopied = 0; // This will track the total number of bytes we've copied
            byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
            int len = 0;
            System.out.println("Total: "+expectedBytes);
            while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
                out.write(buf, 0, len);
                totalBytesCopied += len;
                System.out.println("Len: "+len);
                System.out.println("totalCopiado: "+totalBytesCopied);
                if (expectedBytes != -1) {
                    double total = ( totalBytesCopied * 100 ) / expectedBytes;
                    double percentual = ( totalBytesCopied / expectedBytes ) * 100;
                    System.out.println( total );
                    System.out.println(percentual+"%");
                } else {
                    System.out.println( "???" );
                    System.out.println("???%");
                }
            }
            System.out.println("");
            in.close();
            out.close();
            teste = true;

        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return teste;
    }
```

Note que a ideia foi mudar o mínimo possível o seu código para melhorar o entendimento, não reescrevi de jeito a me agradar a ponto de eu usar em produção.